# Business partner says a wire transfer is being "reviewed" by Homeland Security. Is this normal?

Tags: united-states, international-transfer

My husband has done some consulting for a company outside America. He was told that the company had wired his payment to his U.S. However, his partner told him that the money had "arrived" - but all international wires get reviewed before released. Is this normal?

Answer (score 2):

You should contact Chase and ask them. As long as it's not on your account - it hasn't arrived.

Comment: I'm not sure who the 'partner' referred to in the question is, but if it's a representative of the company that sent the wire, the the sender wouldn't know if Homeland Security was reviewing the transaction. Sounds like an excuse to me.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not "Normal" the normal process is that the money is transferred to your account with out issue.  This would be an exception.  That does not mean that there is anything to worry about.  It could be that the transaction met some criteria that triggered closer examination, or it could be that yours is just one randomly being reviewed.  And it could just be that your husbands partner misunderstood or lied.

Step 1 would be contact the bank and find out what is going on and if there is any action you need to take.

Assuming that the bank confirms the status and the amount is significant enough I would probably give my lawyer a heads up of what is going on.  If Homeland Security is involved there is a reasonable chance that you will need that representation anyway so getting the lawyer involved early might save you a headache in the end.  The lawyer is probably the only person that will be able to get any answers for your anyway.

> *from comments:* My husband is a consultant that works for another company - as a
>   consultant. That company received a contract from a government south
>   of the US (Free Trade approved). That government first wired the
>   overall government contract to the company account in that originating
>   country, then... the funds were wired to the US counterpart company
>   ... then then consultants gets paid.

It sounds like the contract is not your normal business to business international contract.  So normal goes out the window there.  When you start getting foreign governments involved things get... lets use the word "interesting."  If the contract involves anything with military or restricted technology applications (even if they are not directly military) then HSA wants to make sure that no one is circumventing export restrictions.  With out knowing more specifics it is difficult to guess whether or not there is anything for your husband to worry about.  The bottom line for him is that he does not have his money so he should keep that in mind when delivering services to the Prime Contractor.

Comment: ? Welcome back! I hope to see you around.